# Google Forms changes cell reference on different sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm building a spreadsheet to track my macronutrients and calories. I made a google form for inputting information and it populates a "responses" sheet on google sheets. I made a different sheet within the same spreadsheet to perform all the calculation and generate graphs.

But every time I enter a new response into the form, it creates a new row and changes all the cell references in the calculations sheet. For example, I reference cell A2 from the responses

```
='Form Responses'!A2
```

and when I actually fill out the form and it populates, A2 in the responses sheet is filled in but the reference in my calculations sheet has been changed to A3.

```
='Form Responses'!A3
```

I tried using $ but it did the same thing, automatically changes the cell that I referenced.

Any way to have my calcuations sheet reference the newly created rows automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a new tab use for example, = {'Form Responses'! A: Z} and use this data to do your calculations and you will have no problems!

Comment: ={'Form Responses 1'!A2:A} worked for me. thank you

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

To avoid the row value to change reference when adding a new response, you will need to add the `$` next to the number instead of next to the column value (`A`):

`='Form Responses'!A$2`

Moreover, an easy way to reference your whole column is to reference a range instead such as:

`='Form Responses'!A:A`

And then just drag it through your column. If you want it to be more specific (select the range you want):

`='Form Responses'!A2:A999`

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Again, i tried using $ but it was changed all the same. i originally did $A$2 so i put it on both the row and column. i just tried it the way you said and it was still changed. using A:A gave an error throughout my whole column

Comment: i tried referencing the whole column but ='Form Responses'!A:A in a cell shows no values

Comment: Hi Kevin ! It does work in my sheet, could you please share your example sheet (with no sensitive data) so that I can take a better look at it and figure out where the issue might be?

Comment: I made a new form https://forms.gle/DuDWHtFoNkuNBYG78 
and spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ucij7LvyA1ahwawSDH-aJjaRJb_9zbsjKRgWqOaK3_8/edit?usp=sharing

submit a response to the form and it creates a new row on the "Form Responses 1" sheet in the spreadsheet. The second sheet "Sheet 2" in cell A2 has a formula 
='Form Responses 1'!B2
which is changed to
='Form Responses 1'!B3
when a response is submitted. i want it to not change or somehow reference the new row

Comment: @KevinLópez In your example use = {'Form Responses 1'! A: B}

Comment: Hi Kevin ! I have sent you a edit request access so that I can test the formula on your sheet as in mine is working correctly even with the same formatting as yours. Could you please grant it to me? Thanks !